# How replace a character by $_ with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with my PowerShell script and I don't find the answer to my question.

I try to replace:

> ```
>              get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object {
> ```

With:

> ```
>              get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'} | ForEach-Object {
> ```

My code:

```
$old = [regex]::Escape('                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object {')
$new = "                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq `$False} | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'} | ForEach-Object {"
(Get-Content -Path c:\test\test.txt) | ForEach {$_ -Replace "$old","$new"} | Set-Content -Path c:\test\testsuccess
```

Before:

[image: My file test]

After:

[image: The file after running code]

I don't understand why the `$_` is replaced by nothing. I would like to keep `$_` in the output file.

UPDATE 1

I have tried to do

```
$old = [regex]::Escape('                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object {')
$new = "                 get-vm | Where-Object {`$_.IsClustered -eq `$False} | Where-Object {`$_.State -eq 'Running'} | ForEach-Object {"
(Get-Content -Path c:\test\test.txt) | ForEach {$_ -Replace "$old","$new"} | Set-Content -Path c:\test\testsuccess
```

But it doesn't work. The output in the testsuccess file is:

> ```
>              get-vm | Where-Object {                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object { .IsClustered -eq $False} | Where-Object {                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object { .State -eq 'Running'} | ForEach-Object {
> ```

Comment: You must either escape *all* `$` in the replacement string `$new` with a backtick or not escape any of them and use single quotes instead of double quotes for the string.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.

Comment: Oh okay, man, I'll be careful, sorry. @haper

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my post with your proposal. @Ansgar

Comment: @Quetin, check the update of my answer. Code under this [link](https://tio.run/##tZDLCsIwEEX3@YohBKpg/ICCUBALrgS7cCEiMR1aJaY1Sa2gfnuMRQQfS53NwHDg3Ll11aKxJSrlPatUDiNYGizwtIrjiZWixl4E71Og48c9XGBRokE@2@xQOjiz9XBqx6qxLlxz4HgAlgpl8RrQtDITIcsnHPUJ09gG32P9RvOBZk447CA6b7Te6oJ@jUMIc2hd5kxAQpyEkr/8TWjyYuIGayUkwr39QVcG8f4G) works.

Comment: @Moerwald, I go check now thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell parser to do this along with here-strings and the .NET `Replace` method.

```
$parsedcode = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile('c:\test\test.txt',[ref]$null,[ref]$null)

$old = @'
get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object {
'@
$new = @'
get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'} | ForEach-Object {
'@

$parsedcode.ToString().Replace($old,$new) | Out-File c:\test\testsuccess -Force
```

Since we are doing static string replacements, I believe regex is just making this more complicated. The PowerShell language parser can read PowerShell code from a string or file and output it to the console or store it in memory as is. Other capabilities open up using the parser as well.

Using the here-strings (`@''@`) allows for special symbols in the strings to be treated literally.

The `.Replace()` method is a case-sensitive string replacement. It does not use regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$regex = '\sget-vm\s\|\sWhere-Object\s\{\$_\.IsClustered\s-eq\s\$False\}\s\|\sForEach-Object\s\{'
$new = "                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'} | ForEach-Object {"


$testString = '                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object {'
$testString -replace $regex, $new
```

An online version of the above example can be found under [tio.run](https://tio.run/##rZDBDoIwDIbvPEVjluzifANPRhJPJnLwsoRMbEAzAdchJsCzz@EuQDzaY/@//dq/rlo0VKDWzjGDOb5hC1xSjla8HpJkL@lcoEFxvNwxs77TSZbKzYF2uiHrlaskgU8vsFhpQjmEqbgye5UVkzkesRJbv38Fywo46GHKgo6lUw54DATI8MuaWGXxa@KnpixvZc5H3/wQ6FZRxCySTazxlvHdv5yzxPAZRRistcoQQshrGKNw7gM).

You've to be aware to escape special characters like `$` in your regex correctly ( use `\`).

Also, be aware to escape the simple quotes in `$new` correctly. I used the PowerShell [quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) and defined `$new` as "formattable" string to escape ``'Running`'` correctly.

**Update1** (based on @Ansgars comments):

Change quotation of `$new` to:

```
$new = '                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Running"} | ForEach-Object {'
```

When enclosing the string of `$new` in single quotes no substitution actions are performed. In this case, you've to change the single quotes at `'Running'` with double-quotes. An online example can be found [here](https://tio.run/##tZDLCsIwEEX3@YohBKpg/ICCUBALrgS7cCEiMR1aJaY1Sa2gfnuMRQQfS53NwHDg3Ll11aKxJSrlPatUDiNYGizwtIrjiZWixl4E71Og48c9XGBRokE@2@xQOjiz9XBqx6qxLlxz4HgAlgpl8RrQtDITIcsnHPUJ09gG32P9RvOBZk447CA6b7Te6oJ@jUMIc2hd5kxAQpyEkr/8TWjyYuIGayUkwr39QVcG8f4G).

**UPDATE 2**:

Hopefully, this will be the last update. Your problem is related to the .NET defined [substitution elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) (which PowerShell seems to use behind the scenes):

> $_    Includes the entire input string in the replacement string.

In addition PowerShell's quoting rules come into play. Let's check this [example](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Xyk5sUhJQbcotSAnMTlVAczVUVBSiVf6/x8A). We want to replace the word `car` with `$_`:

```
 "car" -replace "car", "$_"
```

The output is empty. Why? Because of using double quotes PowerShell substitutes `$_` with its actual value. Well since nothing is stored in `$_` ( because it was not defined and it normally holds the actual pipeline value, but there is no pipeline included), `car` is replaced to an empty string.

Ok, next [try](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Xyk5sUhJQbcotSAnMTlVAczVUVBXiVf//x8A), lets put `$_` into single quotes:

```
"car" -replace "car", '$_'
```

The output is `car`. Why? Well using single quotes deactivates PowerShell's variable substitutions, and `$_` is forwarded as literal to the `replace` operator. Now the .Net regex substitutions come into play. As stated in [substitution elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) `$_` includes the entire input string, in our case car. So the `-replace` operator replaces `car` with `car`. We can see the entire input is included in this [example](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Xyk5sUhJQbcotSAnMTlVAczVUVBXiddRgGD1//8B):

```
"car" -replace "car", '$_ $_ $_'
```

Output:

```
car car car
```

So, that's the reason why we see this result in the OP:

```
          get-vm | Where-Object {                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object { .IsClustered -eq $False} | Where-Object {                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object { .State -eq 'Running'} | ForEach-Object {
```

Resulting from that it seems that `$_` can't be escaped. The only way I could achieve the request solution for the OP is performing a double substitution (which is not the best way when thinking about performance, maybe there is a better way).

**TL;DR**

[Solution](https://tio.run/##rZDLCsIwEEX3@YqhBqJg/ADBlbTgStCFCxGJ6dAqsa3J@AD122taxLeunM3AcObeO1Pke7QuRWPKkucmhh5MLSZ4mHW7odOqwKZIkORuDSeYpGhRDhcr1ARHPu8MXN9sHflpDBI3wCNlHJ49GuU2VDq9waLFeIZ7L39tAl7ri03jl80bOiZFWEPBaJtlyywJPsZhjBM6GpP1SBXnL0cy1nyUlRYLozRC9dl2fXnrPhQN0QbB/dJTFrlWpNN6pSwv):

```
$old = [regex]::Escape('get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object {')
$new = '                 get-vm | Where-Object {#_.IsClustered -eq $False} | Where-Object {#_.State -eq "Running"} | ForEach-Object {'

$testString = 'get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | ForEach-Object {'

($testString -replace $old, $new) -replace '#', '$'
```

Output:

```
                 get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Running"} | ForEach-Object {
```

So I used `#_` instead of `$_` to deactivate substitution algorithms in general, and perform the first substitution with `#_` in `$new`, which result in:

```
                 get-vm | Where-Object {#_.IsClustered -eq $False} | Where-Object {#_.State -eq "Running"} | ForEach-Object {
```

Now it is easy to substitute `#` with `$`, since `$` alone is not defined in [substitution elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions).

Hope that solve the problem.

Comment: What is escaping the single quotes supposed to accomplish? The problem is that PowerShell expands the `$_` in the double-quoted string b/c the `$` is not escaped.

Comment: The OP uses `[regex]::Escape()`, which already escapes the pattern correctly. Again, the problem is with unescaped `$` characters in the *replacement* string.

Comment: @Moerwald, Thank you for trying to help me and sorry if my post isn't clear but I would like  `get-vm | Where-Object {$_.IsClustered -eq $False} | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Running"} | ForEach-Object {` in output. The front spaces before get-vm are not really important.

Comment: @Quentin, please check Update2 of my answer. I hope I fixed the problem.

Comment: @Moerwald It works well :) but I would like to know if it works in case `#` is also in another place in the text. Are they all going to be changed?

Comment: Yes, but you could a unique pattern instead of `#`. You could e.g. try `#=#`  or something else. The only important thing is that the chars are not part of the regex syntax. If you're fine with the answer please mark it via the checkmark as "resolved". Thx

Comment: tio [link](https://tio.run/##rZDPCsIwDMbvfYrgClWwPoCwkyh4EtzBg4jULmxK3WabOUF99lmH@A/1ZC6B8Mv3fUmRV2hdisbUNc9NDCHMLSZ4WPT7Q6dVgW2RIMn9Fk4wS9GinKw2qAmOfNkbu4EpHflpDBJ3wEfKODx7dJTbodLpHRYdxjOsvPytCXivLzZBGPwy@gBHpAgbrDUts2ydJa2PkRjjhI4ish65RvrLoYy1n2WlxcIojXD9bre5vvMYCh9YdEFwv/aSRm4V6bRZqusL) for `#=#`